# Redirecting real-time SSH Console Output to JFrame

Tags: java, ssh, console, real-time, output

I'm calling plink to execute a a shell script at a remote location using ssh from Java. While I get the buffered data back from the ssh console, I want to write them to a JTextField etc in real time (the backend code executes for about 10 minutes and keeps generating some strings).

While doing that, the execution hangs up till the backend code is completely executed and displays output all at once. If I do it to direct Eclipse console, it writes line by line while executing. Any suggestions?

```
    //JFrame Component
    public GUIApplicationConsoleFrame(String title) {
    dispFrame = new JFrame(title);
    opArea = new JTextArea("");
    ipField = new JTextField();


    // Writing Output, redirected to JTextArea
    if (std.available () > 0) {
            value = std.read ();
            out((char) value);

            while (true) {
                value = std.read ();
                out((char) value);
                if (<terminating condition>)
                    if (++count==2)
                        break;
                Thread.sleep(3);
            }
        }
```

Thanks,
Arya

Answer (score 0):

You should put ssh in a background thread and update the JTextArea from it. That way you will not block the event dispatch thread and it will be able to update graphical interface even if the background (worker) thread is not terminated.